# free jqGrid: wrapping POST data in beforeSubmit function

Tags: javascript, php, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I'm using Oleg's free jqGrid.  After my form editing, I am trying to wrap my POST data, so that in PHP I get a nice array like:

```
Array(
oper => edit,
data => Array(
    foo => '123',
    bar => 'xyz',
    ...
    )
)
```

where the operator and the data on which it operates are nicely separated.

My intuitive approach would have been something like:

```
            beforeSubmit: function( postdata, formid ) {
                    var d = {};
                    d.data = postdata;
                    console.log( d );
                    postdata = d;
                    return( [true, ''] );
            }
```

Unfortuntely this doesn't work; console.log(d) nicely prints the desired result, but postdata is not changed. I am not well-versed in javascript, but I suspect the global postdata is not changed from within the function, and unfortunately the function doesn't allow me to return it.

Any suggestions on how to solve this. It is a minor problem, but I just thought that it looked more structured, and would be more maintainable, to have the clean separation between operator and its data.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback `beforeSubmit` isn't the best choice in your case. Instead of that I'd recommend you to use `serializeEditData` callback, which you can define either as the option of form editing (inside of `formEditing` parameter of jqGrid) or as the parameter of jqGrid. The callback get `postdata` as the only parameter and it should return the modified object of JSON string, which should be sent to the server. The code could be about the following

```
serializeEditData: function (postdata) {
    var d = {
            oper: postdata.oper,
            data: $.extend(true, {}, postdata) // make copy
        };
    delete d.data.oper; // remove unneeded oper property
    return d;
}
```